# How to use Poco to open a secure UDP socket

Tags: c++, network-programming, poco-libraries

I am trying to migrate a system using ACE, which seems to be abandoned at this point.

I have been looking at Poco which seems to be an ideal solution. However for the project I want to be using both a TCP and a UDP socket (VoIP / Video Streaming). Ideally I would like them both to be using TLS by default.

SecureServerSocket and SecureStreamSocket seem to do this well for TCP, and seem to imply I could use SecureStreamSocketImpl for UDP ([here](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.SecureStreamSocketImpl.html#26897)) but I am not sure how? I can't seem to find an example of this being done anywhere.

On the github issues page for Poco there is an open [ticket](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/1320) for using DTLS, which suggests it might not be possible.

**EDIT:** Any other suggestions of how best to secure UDP transmissions would be helpful as well.

Comment: "seem to imply I could use SecureStreamSocketImpl for UDP" - UDP does *not* implement a *stream* - it's more like "fire and forget with no guarantees".

Comment: @JesperJuhl Fair enough, what I was referencing was this comment in the docs for that class. "Initializes the socket and establishes a connection to the TCP server at the given address.

Can also be used for UDP sockets. In this case, no connection is established. Instead, incoming and outgoing packets are restricted to the specified address."

Answer (score 0):

I found this while thinking the same thing. While I have not yet proven it though, I think that is just an erroneous/copy-pasted comment from elsewhere in poco. I have actually found a few things in Poco's handling of Datagrams where the comments (Which match the TCP class comments) do NOT match the implementation.

DTLS is the "Proper" way to secure a UDP socket, but POCO doesn't support it right now (And has a several year old ticket about adding the support... So does Asio)

I'm personally in the process of trying to get DTLS working either alongside or possibly inside of poco. It looks like a pain though.